# Add element to line

Tags: python

I have a log file with (space delimited) numbers. The problem is that the file is too big for autoit (1gig file, memory issues) and I've seen some python magic.
I want to

1. Add an element after the 3rd
2. Remove elements 4-6
3. Do this as fast as possible but with respect to memory limits.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 A 7 8 9

currently my regExp is

```
StringRegExpReplace($line, "(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s", "$1 $2 $3 0 $7 $8 $9")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Python solution anyway:

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as infile:
    with open('filename.out', 'wb') as outfile:        
        for j, line in enumerate(infile):
            if j == 0: #skip first line
                continue
            listLine = line.split(' ')
            listLine.insert(3, thingToInsert) #elements 4-6 are now elements 5-7
            listLine = (el for i, el in enumerate(listLine) if i>4 and i<=7) 
            outfile.write(' '.join(listLine))
```

This will be pretty quick, and won't require too much RAM, since it reads and writes the file line-by-line.

Comment: thnx, i tried that but without the 6th line of code.
  + i'd like to skip the first line.
this code works but is clearly not cheap.  
`with open('demo.txt', 'rb') as infile:
    with open('filename.out', 'wb') as outfile:        
        for line in infile:
      if len(line) > 20:
    print len(line)
    listLine = line.split(' ')
    listLine.insert(3, '0') 
    outfile.write(' '.join(listLine))`

Comment: at the end i went with python, i needed to wrap it into an exe (using py2exe) for portability but its worth it.

Answer (score 2):

[Assuming Windows, I'd probably grab a copy of gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and do it with much less hassle than python.

```
c:\gawk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " added " $7 " " $8 " " $9}' bigfile.log >> outputfile.log
```

Disclaimer: I don't have a Windows machine around to test this, but it would work on the Linux machine I'm currently using...

Comment: ye windows, that was quick, replay and result!  it took 6 minutes with autoit...
btw, cmd refused the single quote. thnx!

Comment: Edited - it probably needs spaces enclosed in quotes between each $n element.  The single quotes wrap the whole awk statement as a single string.

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity I loaded up gawk on my Windows VM. Seems it needs to be double-quotes around the statement, not single.

Comment: another small thing, i need to skip the first line (its a single number with the linecount of the file), possible?